# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Не могу понять что это за ошибка и с чем она связана

```
  import numpy as np


def num_deriv(func):
    def deriv_func(val):
        dx = 1e-10

        x = val[0]
        y = val[1]
        result_x = (func(x + dx, y) - func(x - dx, y)) / (2 * dx)
        result_y = (func(x, y + dx) - func(x, y - dx)) / (2 * dx)

        return np.array([result_x, result_y])

    return deriv_func


def grad_local(func_, deriv_, mas):
    current_point = mas
    STEP_SIZE = 0.01
    step = 0
    current_point
    while step != 40000:
        step += 1
        type(current_point)
        current_point = current_point - STEP_SIZE * num_deriv(func_(current_point))

    return current_point


def f(mas):
    return 2 * mas[0] + 2 * mas[1] ** 2


local = grad_local(f, num_deriv, np.array([1, 1]))
```

Вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/paulr/PycharmProjects/Stepik/Tinkoff/Lectoin1Prac/Prac5.py", line 35, in <module>
    local = grad_local(f, num_deriv, np.array([1, 1]))
  File "C:/Users/paulr/PycharmProjects/Stepik/Tinkoff/Lectoin1Prac/Prac5.py", line 26, in grad_local
    current_point = current_point - STEP_SIZE * num_deriv(func_(current_point))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'
```

Comment: Очевидно, ваш num_deriv возвращает функцию, а умножать число на функцию — довольно бессмысленное занятие

Answer (score 1):

Избегайте такого запутанного кода. Ошибка очевидная - вы пытаетесь дробное число умножить на ф-ю. 
В каком месте? Скорее всего там, где ф-я `num_deriv` вызывает `deriv_func`. Поскольку в `num_deriv` у вас возвращается другая ф-я, а не результат ее выполнения, то в строке `current_point = current_point - STEP_SIZE * num_deriv(func_(current_point))` происходит умножение `STEP_SIZE` на ф-ю. Попробуйте поставить скобки при вызове ф-и `deriv_func` в ф-и `num_deriv`. Возможно я ошибаюсь.